# What exactly happens when a synchronized block cannot acquire the key when working in an asyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-camera

I have a synchronized block in the `onPreviewFrame` function. The reason for that is I'm setting two preview callback for two different camera object and I need to use the `onPreviewFrame` function for them both at the same time. And since the `onPreviewFrame` function is an asychronized function, I want to know what happens when the synchronized block inside the `onPreviewFrame` function cannot acquire the key? Is the `onPreviewFrame` function blocked or is it just jumping through the synchronized block? My code look like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            synchronized (key) {
                 //some code here                   
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread will block until it can acquire the key (more exactly, until it can enter the monitor associated with key).

Comment: Logically yes, the thread will be put into a queue until the monitor becomes free. There is no busy wait.

Comment: "no busy wait" So is there a special queue for all functions that requesting the key and the key is monitoring by the OS or something?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The JVM is taking care of that.